# Generate more data for a small dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, synthetic-data, data-augmentation

I have been working on a dataset which has 14 attributes and 303 rows(instances) along with the binary labels.
I want to generate more data so that I could train my neural networks so that I could increase the accuracy. 
I have read about synthetic data generation but couldn't find a very appropriate explanation. 
I have read that SMOTE is an option but that generally is for class imbalance problem. I am not sure if that would work for generally creating more data. Also, I have read about GANs but again, I am not sure about them. The basic I could gather was that I am looking for a way so that all my present points be present on the feature plane and I generate points in k-nearest neighbours to the points of one label. This was the idea I read about but couldn't get a definitive way how to do the same.
Help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you think you need a neural network for a problem of this scale?

Comment: you are looking for a way to make your work harder. the harder it gets the more mistakes you can make, without any real chance to accomplish a better result.

Comment: @Forgottenscience It is a standard dataset which has been used for various research paper. I am working upon improving the accuracy of the same. Thus I have to use NN. The dataset is https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+Disease.

Comment: @carlo Yes I do get that it might be that with more of synthetic data I am moving towards trouble, but I don't see how I could build a robust model (to the extent possible) with this little data.